# Render Child Component after Parent Component componentDidMount finishes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a third party library Im trying to use. It has a particular prop that  allows you to pass in a string it uses to get a DOM element and return the bottom value.

```
<Sticky bottomBoundary="#some-id">
    <MyChildComponentMightBeANavigationOrAnything />
</Sticky>
```

The component takes the id and determines the bottom value so it knows when to release itself from the sticky status. This id is basically another element in the DOM. So when that elements bottom value reaches the top of the view port the sticky component is allowed to move up as the user scrolls. The problem Im having is I need to add an offset. The Sticky component allows you to pass in a number value instead.

```
<Sticky bottomBoundary={1200}>
    <MyChildComponentMightBeANavigationOrAnything />
</Sticky>
```

I need to add an offset of whatever the sticky elements height is. So lets say that "#some-id" element was 1200px and the height of the sticky element was 50, I need to to be able to get the "#some-id" and subtract 50 before passing the value into bottomBoundary={}. My calculated value would be bottomBoundary={1150}.

I tried the following. I created a component that wraps Sticky as follows:

```
export class WrapperSticky extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.boundary = null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const el = document.querySelector(this.props.bottomBoundary);
        const rect: any = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        this.boundary = rect.bottom - 50;

        console.log(this.boundary);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Sticky innerZ={2000} bottomBoundary={this.boundary}>{this.props.children}</Sticky>
        );
    }
}
```

And I added the markup as follows:

```
<WrapperSticky bottomBoundary="#hero" offset={true}>
    <MyChildComponentMightBeANavigationOrAnything />
</WrapperSticky >
```

Inside the WrapperSticky I attempted to do the calculations in the componentDidMount method and pass the results into the Sticky component. The obvious problem is the Sticky component tries to find the value before the wrapper component has completed the calculations.

Is there a way to do this elegantly. I am very new to react so any articles or documentation to learn from would be a plus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the component state for this. And after calculation finished - update the state, so component re-renders with calculated values.

### `this.state.boundary` vs `this.boundary`

1. Putting boundary value into component's state will help you *by re-rendering on any of its change* (i.e. `setState` call).
2. While plain class fields should be used only if a value *should not affect render result*.

Here is the code:

```
class WrapperSticky extends Component {
  state = {
    boundary: undefined,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const el = document.querySelector(this.props.bottomBoundary)
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()
    const boundary = rect.bottom - 50

    this.setState({ boundary })
  }

  render() {
    const { boundary } = this.state

    return boundary === undefined
      ? null // or placeholder
      : (
        <Sticky innerZ={2000} bottomBoundary={boundary}>
          {this.props.children}
        </Sticky>
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a boolean flag in the state of `WrapperSticky` for whether you've done the calculation yet.  It's initially false, and `render` returns `<></>`.  In `componentDidMount`, after you do the calculation, you set the flag to true, which triggers a re-render that renders the child for real.  This should at least work (I've done something similar [here](https://bitbucket.org/espalier-spreadsheet/espalier/src/95002d5bd6688178a3befd1ac27c9a8ee9fe3677/src/layout/client/rendering.tsx?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#rendering.tsx-159) using the `subProps` state field), though there might be a better way using some of the more advanced lifecycle hooks.

Comment: Thank you. Let me check out your code. Hopefully someone will contribute in who we can both learn from.